# MySql: among 20000 rows of records only shows 5, why?

Tags: python, mysql, performance, query-optimization

I want to test my MySQL database and how it handles my future data. it is only a table with two columns, one of the column is only one word and another one is 30.000 characters in. So I copied and inserted into the same table 20.000 times that shows the size is 2.0 GB. Now I want to browse them through phpMyAdmin it shows nothing and every destroyed that table to show anything. I output it through python it only shows 5 rows that were inserted before this copy.   I used a script to delete rows from IDs between 5000 - 10.000 it works. That means that data is there but doesn't come out. Any explanation?

```
    import MySQLdb as mdb        
con = mdb.connect('127.0.0.1', 'root','password', 'database')
title = []
entry = []
y = 0
with con:            
    conn = con.cursor()

    conn.execute("SELECT * FROM mydatabase WHERE id='2' AND myword = 'jungleboy'")
    rows = conn.fetchall()    
    for i in rows:
         title.append(i[1])
         entry.append(i[2])

    for x in range(20000):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO mydatabase(myword,explanation) VALUES (%s,%s)",(str(title[0]),str(entry[0])))
        if x > y+50:
            print str(x)
            y = x
```

Comment: Python that I used it to INSERT and QUERY.

Comment: Next time tag your question with python then, please.

Comment: But the problem is in the MySql, isn't it?

Comment: Impossible to tell with the information you've given us.  You haven't for example, shown how you output the data through python.

Comment: such problem directed to and can be solved by an advanced and experienced one. And the one who is advanced knows how to output those data through any language. so the answer is, I tried to output through python IDLE and also wx.python.

Comment: We don't have a crystal ball here, which is what your question currently requires.  Show us -your- code, for outputting the text.  We'll never know if it's the problem or not until you show us what you've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but here are some tips with the code you have pasted.

After any `INSERT` or other query that adds, removes or changes data in a table, you need to commit the transaction with `con.commit()`.

There is a limit on how many records can be fetched with `fetchall()`. You can see and adjust this limit by printing the `arraysize` attribute of the cursor:

```
print 'I can only fetch {0.arraysize} rows at a time.'.format(cur)
```

To guarantee that you are fetching every row, loop through the results, like this:

```
q = "SELECT .... " # some query that returns a lot of results
conn.execute(q)
rows = con.fetchone() # or fetchall()

while rows:
   print rows
   rows = con.fetchone() # again, or fetchall()
```

Comment: Thanks it's been a while I am using the same method I used before and it works to insert 2000 rows while before it got failed. but I have to test it more to see why it happens. and I also tested con.commit() that I believe it is a good idea to make your table after changing be stable. but it is only my theory and needs more test to do. so next time I try a very large entry and see what happens. but it is strange that for only 2000 entry, my table reached 350 MBit that lost my appetite to use database and these stuffs anymore.